# Free source of printable star charts in the format of the Millennium Star Atlas?

Tags: amateur-observing

I've been looking for sources of printable electronic star charts - there seem to be many different ones available, either as part of planetarium software or just plain charting packages. But there's such a richness of offerings that I'm having trouble figuring out which of those, if any, can produce printable charts in the format that I'm looking for.

I like the general format of the Millennium Star Atlas - black stars on a white sky background, and with horizontal lines representing 1 degree of declination and vertical lines representing 4 minutes of RA (see sample page at http://www.skyandtelescope.com/wp-content/uploads/GD-Sept2011-Chart.pdf ).

I'd like to be able to specify a range of RA and declination and get that chart.

Can anyone suggest any free star chart printing software that can print similar output for any desired sector of the sky?

I'm looking at Cartes du Ciel (http://sourceforge.net/projects/skychart/) which might have that capability, but if so, I haven't yet figured out how to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think that I've found the answer - it looks like Cartes du Ciel will do what I'm looking for (although I haven't yet figured out the simplest workflow).

Click on the icon for Equatorial Coordinates

Then click on the icon for 'configure the program'

Under the Colour tab, click on 'black on white'

Under the Lines tab, make sure that 'show grid label' and 'show coordinates grid - line' are checked.

Zoom in to the desired magnification

Click on printer icon